# Weird behaviour as I try to print a char array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I declared a 2D char array and it is uninitialized. When I am trying to print the element in console(I am using eclipse) using a nested loop it does not print anything from the array and that is ok because it is filled with null. But, the weird part is I am not able to print anything in the outer loop as well. Not only that the `println()` statement immediately after the outer loop block does not print anything. The next one works. Here is the code,

```
private char oceanMap[][] = new char[10][10];
private void showOceanMap() {
        System.out.println("  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  ");
        int c = 0, r = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            r++;
            System.out.println("Hey");
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
                c++;
                System.out.print(this.oceanMap[i][j]+"-");
            }
            //s+="|"+Integer.toString(i);
        }
        System.out.println("  0 1 2 3 4 5 6  ");
        System.out.println("  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  ");
        System.out.println("r = "+r+" and c = "+c);
    }
```

When I call the method `showOceanMap()` it gives the following output:

[image: Output]

The same code when running in jdoodle is working as expected. 
when I initialize the array then it works fine in both ides. That imply that it is because of initialization issue, but why would the other `println()` statements wont work? I am not getting any exception or error. 
An explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Don't post a screen shot it decrease readability of the post. Post the out pout only as text.

Comment: Try removing or commenting out `System.out.print(this.oceanMap[i][j]+"-");` line from the inner loop, and see if then loops iterate correctly.

Comment: Your array is not filled with null. Every entry is 0.

Comment: could not reproduce the problem. It prints fully in eclipse.

Comment: [For type char, the default value is the null character, that is, '\u0000'.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) So your trying printing out the null character, which is not printable, seems to confusing your console. For me (Linux bash) it prints out correctly "Hey ----------" for each `i`.

Comment: @AxelRichter It seemed to me as some problem with the ide as well. in Jdoodle it worked perfectly.

Comment: @wdc if I remove the line, it works as expected. The loop was running ok. the value in variables r and c suggest that. I am confused, why the println() in outer loop or the one after dont work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AmitBera. will keep that in mind.

Comment: @KushalMondal Well, as It did print `Hay` once, I guess that printing that uninitialized array throws some exception and stops the loop. Try catching the exception and printing the stack trace to see if exception is being thrown.